# after subsequent clicks, paper-dropwn-menu list items seem to be crunched up

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer, paper-elements

I recreated the top item from the DropDown demos, at https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-dropdown-menu

The only thing different I did was replace the strings with "Internal"and "External".  It seemed that when the DDL is rendered on the screen, the first time it works correctly when it is clicked, but then subsequent times, it is made really small with a scroll bar that you cant really see.

You can see what the form looks like first, what it looks like when i click on it the first time.... and what i click on it the second time respectively.

[image: What the form looks like. Type is the DDL]
[image: Looks fine after the first click.]
[image: Looking all jacked up.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issues, there isTo resolve this issue, there is an attribute called: `no-animations` you can add to the `paper-dropdwon-menu` which will stop animations and cause it to render correctly.

based on Polymer styling, you can say either just:  `no-animations` or `no-animations="true"`

```
<paper-dropdown-menu no-animations="true">
    ....
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the older Dartium version that is based on Chromium 39. I haven't checked the newer Dartium that is based on Chromium 45. AFAIR the newer version is shipped since Dart 1.15 but perhaps only with 1.16-dev. If you try it in a current Chrome version it should work as expected.

Comment: Correct, a bug in previous versions of Dartium. Fixed in Dartium based on Chromium 45. In the Dart sdk 1.15.

Comment: Can you do a version based `no-animations` attribute?